# Gimp cannot show visible some layers?

Tags: gimp

Can anyone explain why Gimp can't open 50% of the layers in [this PSD](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dl3tvmknfm05p3h/AAAK3E9BrDgznzZK5MxmrUava?dl=0&preview=leverex_1140_grid.psd)?

I couldn't find any article about the same problem on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its PSD support is missing something. Report the problem on their [GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues) and attach the file.